# Sluggish and slow Finder on MacOs Sierra 10.12.6

Tags: macos, performance, finder, macos-sierra

I have a Macbook Pro 15" Mid 2014, 16GB RAM, Core i7, 512 GB SSD.

I'm noticing that very often operations in Finder are VERY slow : copy, move, delete, get info (right click) on files and so on. When this happens, that colored circle appears, and if i check Activity Monitor, i can see Finder is using more than 100% of CPU.

I don't have further information about this issue, i just know if did not happen until the last few weeks.

I don't want to format / reinstall the OS, i'm software developer and would be a hassle to configure my environment again. Is there anything i could do / check to solve the issue ?

Thanks !

Comment: Are the slow copies just within the SSD, or is there an external HDD or USB flash drive or server involved?

Comment: By colored circle do you mean the icon that looks like a beach ball which spins?

Comment: @jmh Yes, that one.

Comment: @spiff No external, only copies whithin the SSD